# Laid off what happens to FSA money?

Tags: united-states, hsa

My husband was laid off from his job and he had an FSA healthcare account.  The account shows there is over $600 available.  What happens to that money now that he's laid off and no longer worker for the employer?

Comment: It's very likely the money is gone. Unless he got extended health benefits as part of a severance package, in that case he might have access to the funds for a short amount of time.